# How to serve a custom index.html using the stock nginx docker image?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, nginx, servers

How do I serve static content from the default `nginx` docker image?  Given:

```
root@mordor:~# 
root@mordor:~# docker image ls nginx
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
nginx               latest              c39a868aad02        8 days ago          133MB
root@mordor:~#
```

where and how can a hello world be configured?

In the context of:

https://askubuntu.com/q/1292182/847449

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "official" nginx image has a specific path where it looks for files. You can either copy a file into the image by creating a new image from it or mount your files into this path as a volume.

To copy files, have a folder with your `index.html` and a `Dockerfile` that looks like this:

```
FROM nginx
COPY index.html /usr/share/nginx/html
```

Then build a new image with `docker build -t my-nginx .`

To start a container with your own files as a volume, you can run the container like this:

```
docker run -p 8080:80 -v ${PWD}:/usr/share/nginx/html nginx
```

All the files in your current folder (including the `index.html`) will now be available via `http://localhost:8080/index.html`.

Most of this information is covered in the documentation for the image at https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx

Answer (score 1):

running and copying files into the container:

```
root@mordor:~# 
root@mordor:~# sudo docker run --name docker-nginx -p 80:80 -d nginx
29b4280504c2d46c10b8459de0844ba30bce0c1bc97b70521c3f812f29d17c27
root@mordor:~# 
root@mordor:~# docker cp index.html docker-nginx:/indx.html
root@mordor:~# 
root@mordor:~# docker exec -it docker-nginx bash
root@29b4280504c2:/# 
root@29b4280504c2:/# ls
bin   dev          docker-entrypoint.sh  home       lib    media  opt   root  sbin  sys  usr
boot  docker-entrypoint.d  etc           indx.html  lib64  mnt    proc  run   srv   tmp  var
root@29b4280504c2:/# 
root@29b4280504c2:/# cd /usr/share/nginx/html/
root@29b4280504c2:/usr/share/nginx/html# 
root@29b4280504c2:/usr/share/nginx/html# ls
50x.html  index.html
root@29b4280504c2:/usr/share/nginx/html# 
root@29b4280504c2:/usr/share/nginx/html# mv index.html index.html.bkup
root@29b4280504c2:/usr/share/nginx/html# 
root@29b4280504c2:/usr/share/nginx/html# cp /indx.html ./index.html
root@29b4280504c2:/usr/share/nginx/html# 
root@29b4280504c2:/usr/share/nginx/html# exit
exit
root@mordor:~# 
root@mordor:~# docker container list
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                NAMES
29b4280504c2        nginx               "/docker-entrypoint.…"   2 minutes ago       Up 2 minutes        0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp   docker-nginx
root@mordor:~# 
root@mordor:~# docker stop docker-nginx
docker-nginx
root@mordor:~# 
root@mordor:~# docker start docker-nginx
docker-nginx
root@mordor:~#
```

so that:

```
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ lynx http://localhost/ --dump
   hello nginx docker world
nicholas@mordor:~$
```